# Access parent scope from child object

Tags: angularjs

**Technology:** AngularJS

**Context:**

I have two directives : row and column. In row's template, a have a ng-repeat like so:

```
<column ng-repeat="column in row.childs"></column>
```

In column's directive, I have two objects in my scope: column and settings. "settings" needs to be outside "column" and both are accessed inside the column's template.

**Question:**

Is there a way to retrieve the parent scope of the "column" object so I could access "settings"? Something like:

```
column.scope().settings
```

I know I could retrieve the column's scope by either passing it through a  parameter or by using `angular.element('#' + column.id).scope()` but I would like to avoid that for structural and performance reasons.

Maybe there is a way to retrieve the scope from $$hashKey?

Comment: Have you tried using the `$parent` property of the columns scope? Additonally the code of the column directive seems useful to add..

Comment: @kenda, $parent is only accessible from the scope. "column" is not a scope, but a sub-object.

Comment: Right, so I don't get your question and what you mean by retrieving a scope from a simple object :-/

Comment: @kenda, as I reread my question I feel that it's not clear indeed. However I did find a solution which I answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my issue!

In "column"'s directive, I simply created a function:

```
/**
 * Get widget's scope
*/
$s.column.getScope = function() {

    return $s;
};
```

And it works great.